# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command without ToList()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the method below to load dependent data from navigation property. However, it generates an error. I can remove the error by adding `ToList()` or `ToArray()`, but I'd rather not do that for performance reasons. I also cannot set the `MARS` property in my web.config file because it causes a problem for other classes of the connection.

How can I solve this without using extension methods or editing my `web.config`?

```
public override void Load(IEnumerable<Ques> data)
{

    if (data.Any())
    {
        foreach (var pstuu in data)
        {
            if (pstuu?.Id_user != null)
            {
                db.Entry(pstuu).Reference(q => q.Users).Load();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to the issue, but please try to avoid this level of nesting. Please try to use early exit instead like: `if (!data.Any()) return;`

Comment: Usually, this means you are trying to re-use the same connection object. This is bad. Only try to re-use the connection string, and let your code create a new connection for each query.

Comment: Arrow pattern! Where's db come from? ToList() is when the context goes back to the database to fetch.

Comment: `but I'd rather not do that for performance reasons` ← Can you elaborate? If you have to iterate over the entire collection either way why not get it in memory first and then iterate? If it is not an option consider using a secondary dbcontext. Another option is to use `AsNoTracking().ToList()` which will speed up the retrieval just remember to add any instance back to the context tracking if you want to persist a change.

Comment: @GHDevOps  I'am in the (QuestionRepository : BaseRepository<Question>) and db is injected in the constructor ( public BaseRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            this.db = context;
        } )

Comment: @Igor how to use secondary dbcontext in the constructor of repository ? and in my code data.AsNoTracking().ToList() dosn't work data is of type Ienumerable

Comment: @mecab95 - are you sure the underlying type is not of type IQueryable<T>? That would make more sense as you mentioned the DbContext stays open and you can fix it with ToList. Change the method signature to accept IQueryable instead of IEnumerable or pass in a List to begin with and call the AsNoTracking.ToList one level higher up in the stack.

Comment: @Igor i have changed type of param with iquerable and i have added data.AsNoTracking().ToList() but i have an error in db.Entry(qst).Reference(q => q.AspNetUsers).Load();  ( 'Member 'Load' cannot be called for property 'AspNetUsers' because the entity of type 'Ques' does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet<Ques>.') i don't know why and i have used LoadAsynch it works without adding ToList() for the data

Comment: Looks like you need to have it attached to the db context to perform that action so `AsNoTracking` is not an option for you.

Comment: @Igor I delete it and i have replaced Load with Loadasynch it works !! without using ToList() but also time of response is like when i use ToList()

Comment: It is actually **worse** to not use `ToList`, because you are enumerating `data` multiple times. The reason you are getting the error is because `data` is not fully enumerated. And calling `.Load` in a `foreach` is called the `N + 1` anti-pattern, and is itself a really bad idea.

Comment: " I delete it and i have replaced Load with Loadasynch it works !! without using ToList()" If you just replaced `db.Entry(qst).Reference(q => q.AspNetUsers).Load();` with `db.Entry(qst).Reference(q => q.AspNetUsers).LoadAsync();` and think it "works", it won't be working, it will just continue immediately without error because it's been delegated to an un-awaited task.  Looking at this code is what looks to be a perfect example of the rabbit hole that development teams get caught in when trying to abstract away EF.

Comment: If setting MARS causes other problems then *those* problems should be solved. Not this one.

Comment: @GertArnold i have 'MultipleActiveResultsSets' Keyword Not Supported in this line (  if (userManager.FindByEmail(adminUserName) == null) ) how solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by deletion the method `Load` and I have used `Include()` in my first query of data to show the reference data in navigation property

Answer (score 0):

I take it from this question you've got a situation something like:

```
// (outside code)
var query = db.SomeEntity.Wnere(x => x.SomeCondition == someCondition);
LoadDependent(query);
```

Chances are based on this method it's probably a call stack of various methods that build search expressions and such, but ultimately what gets passed into `LoadDependent()` is an `IQueryable<TEntity>`.

Instead if you call:

```
// (outside code)
var query = db.SomeEntity.Wnere(x => x.SomeCondition == someCondition);
var data = query.ToList();
LoadDependent(data);
```

Or.. in your LoadDependent changing doing something like:

```
base.LoadDependent(data);
data = data.ToList();
```

or better,

```
foreach (Ques qst in data.ToList())
```

Then your `LoadDependent()` call works, but in the first example you get an error that a DataReader is open. This is because your `foreach` call as-is would be iterating over the `IQueryable` meaning EF's data reader would be left open so further calls to `db`, which I'd assume is a module level variable for the DbContext that is injected, cannot be made.

Replacing this:

```
db.Entry(qst).Reference(q => q.AspNetUsers).Load();
```

with this:

```
db.Entry(qst).Reference(q => q.AspNetUsers).LoadAsync();
```

... does not actually work. This just delegates the load call asynchronously, and without awaiting it, it too would fail, just not raise the exception on the continuation thread.

As mentioned in the comments to your question this is a very poor design choice to handle loading references. You are far, far better off enabling lazy loading and taking the Select n+1 hit if/when a reference is actually needed if you aren't going to implement the initial fetch properly with either eager loading or projection.

Code like this *forces* a Select n+1 pattern throughout your code.

A good example of loading a "Ques" with it's associated User eager loaded:

```
var ques = db.Ques
    .Include(x => x.AspNetUsers)
    .Where(x => x.SomeCondition == someCondition)
    .ToList();
```

Whether "SomeCondition" results in 1 Ques returned or 1000 Ques returned, the data will execute with one query to the DB.

Select n+1 scenarios are bad because in the case where 1000 Ques are returned with a call to fetch dependencies you get:

```
var ques = db.Ques
    .Where(x => x.SomeCondition == someCondition)
    .ToList(); // 1 query.

foreach(var q in ques)
     db.Entry(q).Reference(x => x.AspNetUsers).Load(); // 1 query x 1000
```

1001 queries run. This compounds with each reference you want to load.

Which then looks problematic where later code might want to offer pagination such as to take only 25 items where the total record count could run in the 10's of thousands or more.  This is where lazy loading would be the lesser of two Select n+1 evils, as with lazy loading you know that AspNetUsers would only be selected *if* any returned Ques actually referenced it, and only for those Ques that actually reference it. So if the pagination only "touched" 25 rows, Lazy Loading would result in 26 queries. Lazy loading is a trap however as later code changes could inadvertently lead to performance issues appearing in seemingly unrelated areas as new referenences or code changes result in far more references being "touched" and kicking off a query.

If you are going to pursue a `LoadDependent()` type method then you need to ensure that it is called as late as possible, once you have a known set size to load because you will need to materialize the collection to load related entities with the same DbContext instance. (I.e. after pagination) Trying to work around it using detached instances (`AsNoTracking()`) or by using a completely new DbContext instance may give you some headway but will invariably lead to more problems later, as you will have a mix of tracked an untracked entities, or worse, entities tracked by different DbContexts depending on how these loaded entities are consumed.

An alternative teams pursue is rather than a LoadReference() type method would be an IncludeReference() type method. The goal here being to build `.Include` statements into the `IQueryable`. This can be done two ways, either by magic strings (property names) or by passing in expressions for the references to include. Again this can turn into a bit of a rabbit hole when handling more deeply nested references. (I.e. building `.Include().ThenInclude()` chains.) This avoids the Select n+1 issue by eager loading the required related data.

Comment: Include dosn't load references for me in this case i don't know what , how can i use secondary db context ?

Comment: I have found in my project tat this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false in class context

Comment: `.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false` would disable lazy loading entirely, leaving you to either eager load related entities (`Include`), exclusively load them (`Load()`, but only after your set is loaded /w `ToList()`) or projection, using `Select()`.  You almost certainly wouldn't want to try to use a second DbContext, that is more of a warning in case it is something you find and think to try. :) Teams will disable lazy loading because it's seen as "bad" but then end up implementing something worse (explicit load) or far more complex and/or error prone.

Comment: I have solved the problem by delete the method LoadDepend and I have used Include() in my first query of data to show the reference data in navigation property and to avoid to use ToList because it takes munch time to excute many records and to show the error There is already an open DataReader